# write to file from nested for loop with try statement

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator

I am seeking some way to make this nested for loop more pythonic. Specifically, how can I iterate through unique combinations of three variables, and write to file if data is present in the dictionary?

```
foo,bar = {},{} #filling of dicts not shown
with open(someFile,'w') as aFile:
    for year in years:
        for state in states:
            for county in counties:
                try:foo[year,state,county],bar[state,county]
                except:continue
                aFile.write("content"+"\n")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just iterate over the keys of `foo` and then check if `bar` has a corresponding key:

```
for year, state, county in foo:
    if (state, county) in bar:
        aFile.write(...)
```

This way you avoid iterating over anything that won't at least work for `foo`.

The disadvantage to this is that you don't know what order the keys will be iterated in.  If you need them in sorted order you could do `for year, state, county in sorted(foo)`.

As @Blckknght pointed out in a comment, this method also will always write for every matching key.  If you want to exclude some years/states/counties you could add that to the `if` statement (e.g., `if (state, county) in bar and year > 1990` to exclude years before 1990, even if they are already in the dict).

Comment: This might not work right if the `years`, `states` and `counties` sequences are more restricted than the keys of `foo` or `bar`.

Comment: @Blckknght: That's true, but you can fairly easily get around that by putting extra restrictions in the `if` statement.  I edited my answer.

Comment: I seem to get the same output when using `sorted(foo)` and `sorted(foo.iterkeys())`. What's the advantage to `sorted(foo.iterkeys())`?

Comment: @metasequoia: Sorry, I just have a habit of using `iterkeys` to make it clear I'm using the keys.  You can use `sorted(foo)` just the same.

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion of using `itertools.product` to generate the values you'll use as keys has already been made. I want to add some improvements in the "easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" style exception handling you're doing:

```
import itertools

with open(some_file, "w"):
    for year, state, county in itertools.product(years, states, counties):
        try:
            something_from_foo = foo[(year, state, county)]
            something_from_bar = bar[(state, count)]

            # include the write in the try block
            aFile.write(something_from_foo + something_from_bar)

        except KeyError: # catch only a specific exception, not all types
            pass
```

Comment: +1 valuable suggestion on `itertools.product` to avoid forgiveness > permission approach